# Redirect sitewide to non .php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have a website - https://www.leiebilguiden.no. A long time ago we changed to wordpress. There are still a lot of incoming links with a .php extension. For example https://www.leiebilguiden.no/spania/alicante.php.

The address that works now is https://www.leiebilguiden.no/spania/alicante/. Using htaccess and redirect how can we redirect all incoming links (not just the one above) with a php extension to a non php extension like seen above.

Thank you in advance for all answers.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: You will find thousands of existing answers and suggestions for this here on StackOverflow. I suggest that you first do some research, then try to implement the required rules yourself. We are here to _help_ with issues you fail to solve yourself. But for that you need to start out yourself and post the rules you implemented yourself so far. Along with a precise description what it is that you cannot solve yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Please see above. I have updated the code that I have.

Comment: The redirection needs to be done _before_ the wordpress rules get applied. So you need to place those rules _above_ the wordpress rules in that distributed configuration file.